# Set one of the item in menu bar to default (when first launch the webpage)

Tags: html, css

i have a question about the menu bar. I want to set an item in menu bar to active or focus at default, but my default selected item in menu bar would remain at active even I choose other item in menu bar. Here is my html code.

```css
.nav_bar nav {
    float:left;
    font-size: 12pt;
    text-align:center;
    width:15%;
    background: #5A9ACB;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin:0px 0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.nav_bar nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0px;
}

.nav_bar nav ul li{
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    border-bottom-color:#DADFFF;
}

.nav_bar nav a:link,.nav_bar nav a:visited{
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 13px 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav_bar nav a:hover, .nav_bar nav a:active, .nav_bar nav .active a:link,.nav_bar nav .active a:visited{
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#226EA8;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.nav_bar nav a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background: #1B6298;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.nav_bar nav ul li span{
     color:#085087;
     font-size:20pt;
     position:absolute;
     left:175px;
}

.nav_bar nav a:hover span{
     color:#ffffff;
}

.nav_bar nav li ul a{
    background: #5A9ACB;
}

.nav_bar nav li ul{
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    height:0px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    margin:0px;
    margin-left:190px;
    margin-top:-56px;
    padding:0px;
}

.nav_bar nav li:hover ul{
    display:block;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="nav_bar">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Event</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lost & Found</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Management<span>&#10097;</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Student Management</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Program Management</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: did you try adding the `active` class to the respective `li` element you want to be active on each page? Don't confuse an `.active` class with the `:active` pseudo selector.

Comment: yes but stil not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep your code and add this on your code may help you (on head)

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
        $('ul li').click(function(e) 
    { 
        $("div nav ul li.active").removeClass("active");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: work like a charm! This code is simple enough to understand, thanks man

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like that:

```js
function MenuCtrl($) {
  var self = this;
  
  self.items = $('#menu li');
  self.ACTIVE_CLASS = 'is-active';
  
  self.items.click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    self.items
      .removeClass(self.ACTIVE_CLASS)
      .filter($(this))
      .addClass(self.ACTIVE_CLASS)
    ;
  });
  
  self.items.get(0).click();
  // or, finding on the dom what is the default element
  //self.items.filter('.is-default').click();
}

jQuery(document).ready(MenuCtrl);
```

```css
ol { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
li {padding: 0 1em; list-style-position: inside; width: 100%; line-height: 2em; transition: 500ms all linear; background: transparent; cursor: pointer; }
.is-active { background-color: lightseagreen; cursor: default; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol id="menu">
  <li>Menu Item 1</li>
  <li>Menu Item 2</li>
  <li>Menu Item 3</li>
  <li>Menu Item 4</li>
  <li class="is-default">Menu Item 5</li>
  <li>Menu Item 6</li>
  <li>Menu Item 7</li>
  <li>Menu Item 8</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: any way can set one of the item in vertical menu bar to default selected (to show that you are currently in which page) without using js. just pure css or html

Comment: Why  doing that without js?

By the way, you need some marker that indicates you which the default item is... at least you maybe do something similar with nth-child selectors, for example: 

ul > li:first-child { background: red; }

Assuming that the first li element is the default item!